Why isn't my math block rendering on GitHub?
I have the following math block in a README.md:
\begin{split}
    \frac{\partial Q_0}{\partial \Lambda_0}
    &=
    \frac{I_{0}^{2} \Lambda_{0}^{4} + I_{0}^{2} \Lambda_{0}^{2} \Lambda_{1}^{2} - I_{0} I_{1} \Lambda_{0}^{2} \sqrt{\Lambda_{0}^{2} + \Lambda_{1}^{2}} + I_{0} I_{1} \Lambda_{1}^{2} \sqrt{\Lambda_{0}^{2} + \Lambda_{1}^{2}} - I_{1}^{2} \Lambda_{0}^{4} - I_{1}^{2} \Lambda_{0}^{2} \Lambda_{1}^{2}}{I_{0}^{2} \left(\Lambda_{0}^{2} + \Lambda_{1}^{2}\right)^{2}} \\
    \frac{\partial Q_1}{\partial \Lambda_0}
    &=
    \frac{\Lambda_{0} \Lambda_{1} \left(I_{0}^{2} \sqrt{\Lambda_{0}^{2} + \Lambda_{1}^{2}} - 2 I_{0} I_{1} - I_{1}^{2} \sqrt{\Lambda_{0}^{2} + \Lambda_{1}^{2}}\right)}{I_{0}^{2} \left(\Lambda_{0}^{2} + \Lambda_{1}^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \\
    \frac{\partial Q_0}{\partial \Lambda_1}
    &=
    \frac{\Lambda_{0} \Lambda_{1} \left(I_{0}^{2} \sqrt{\Lambda_{0}^{2} + \Lambda_{1}^{2}} - 2 I_{0} I_{1} - I_{1}^{2} \sqrt{\Lambda_{0}^{2} + \Lambda_{1}^{2}}\right)}{I_{0}^{2} \left(\Lambda_{0}^{2} + \Lambda_{1}^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \\
    \frac{\partial Q_1}{\partial \Lambda_1}
    &=
    \frac{I_{0}^{2} \Lambda_{0}^{2} \Lambda_{1}^{2} + I_{0}^{2} \Lambda_{1}^{4} + I_{0} I_{1} \Lambda_{0}^{2} \sqrt{\Lambda_{0}^{2} + \Lambda_{1}^{2}} - I_{0} I_{1} \Lambda_{1}^{2} \sqrt{\Lambda_{0}^{2} + \Lambda_{1}^{2}} - I_{1}^{2} \Lambda_{0}^{2} \Lambda_{1}^{2} - I_{1}^{2} \Lambda_{1}^{4}}{I_{0}^{2} \left(\Lambda_{0}^{2} + \Lambda_{1}^{2}\right)^{2}}
\end{split}

When I use Pandoc with gfm formatting, it renders, but on the GitHub preview it says Unable to render expression. I've tried trimming it down to identify the problem, but even when I change a symbol from \Lambda_{0}^{2} to \Lambda_0^2 it seems to affect whether it is rendered or not.
How should I go about debugging this?
Edit 1: At the suggestion of the comments, I've removed everything that I can while still reproducing the problem. Unfortunately it seems that the first two lines need to remain the same, and I can only partially reduce the third line:
\begin{split}
    \frac{\partial Q_0}{\partial \Lambda_0}
    &=
    \frac{I_{0}^{2} \Lambda_{0}^{4} + I_{0}^{2} \Lambda_{0}^{2} \Lambda_{1}^{2} - I_{0} I_{1} \Lambda_{0}^{2} \sqrt{\Lambda_{0}^{2} + \Lambda_{1}^{2}} + I_{0} I_{1} \Lambda_{1}^{2} \sqrt{\Lambda_{0}^{2} + \Lambda_{1}^{2}} - I_{1}^{2} \Lambda_{0}^{4} - I_{1}^{2} \Lambda_{0}^{2} \Lambda_{1}^{2}}{I_{0}^{2} \left(\Lambda_{0}^{2} + \Lambda_{1}^{2}\right)^{2}} \\
    \frac{\partial Q_1}{\partial \Lambda_0}
    &=
    \frac{\Lambda_{0} \Lambda_{1} \left(I_{0}^{2} \sqrt{\Lambda_{0}^{2} + \Lambda_{1}^{2}} - 2 I_{0} I_{1} - I_{1}^{2} \sqrt{\Lambda_{0}^{2} + \Lambda_{1}^{2}}\right)}{I_{0}^{2} \left(\Lambda_{0}^{2} + \Lambda_{1}^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \\
    \frac{\partial Q_0}{\partial \Lambda_1}
    &=
    \frac{I_{0}^{2} \sqrt{\Lambda_{0}^{2}}}{I_{0}^{2} \left(\Lambda_{0}^{2} + \Lambda_{1}^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{split}

Any other terms that I remove cause it to be correctly rendered.

Remove everything, add it back line by line until it stops rendering?

Start trimming it down more. Don't replace terms, remove them. Ignore what the math says, and start removing terms in a LaTeX legal way until you've removed everything that can be removed while still reproducing the problem.

If "any other terms that I remove cause it to be correctly rendered" and it doesn't matter which you remove, that suggests you're hitting some kind of character limit. Time to write in to GitHub and ask them to check if that's the case and if so, whether they can update their LaTeX support doc?
